# aws lambda: authentication with Cognito and a fixed user

Tags: authentication, aws-lambda

I have a web application where people can upload files and I want a login for this so some functions can only be accessed by people who are logged in. I want to have one fixed pair of username and password, so there should be no option for users to create their own account (only the people who have the right information can access). I have a login paige where I proof with JavaScript if the fields are filled and if they are there should be invoked a lambda function to set the user to auth in Cognito to login. I created a fixed user in Cognito with username and password and I now want to proof if the entries of the fields are the same like the created user so that the user is logged in and can use the functions on the web app.

I read a lot of tutorials how to set up an authentication with cognito and lambda, but totally different to what I want to do. So I really have no idea how I can write the lambda function to do what I want.
Has anyone an idea how I can build up my plan or is it a bad idea like that?
Thank you for your help

Comment: usually when asking questions on StackOverflow it's a good idea to post some code to help people figure out what you're trying to achieve, although I appreciate with the AWS stuff it can be tough because there are a lot of elements. Welcome to StackOverflow!

Comment: To be clear you've logged into cognito successfully and now what to get your user information in a lambda function?

Answer (score 0):

you don't need the user/pass, in api gateway in the lambda method set the auth type to AWS_IAM, so only auth users will be able to call the lambda method... and then only that specific user will be able to call your lambda method.

inside the lambda method you can access 
event.requestContext.identity.cognitoAuthenticationProvider
and
event.requestContext.identity.cognitoIdentityId

to get the user that was auth by AWS

Comment: I don't work with API, only with S3, DynamoDB and Lambda so I guess that will not work for me. But the idea with only allowing the one user to call the lambda is interesting.

Comment: in your Auth role, you can add access to the lambda method:

`{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": “xxx”,
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "execute-api:Invoke"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:execute-api:us-east-1:xxx:xxx/*/POST/METHODNAME”
            ]
        }
    ]
}`

Comment: I'm sorry it's the first time I'm working with Lambda. So I understand what you showed me but I don't understand how I can set my user to auth. So if I have my JavaScript and I'm having a look that my username and password are not empty I have to proof if they are the same as the ones I have with my created user. And only if this is ok I can call the lambda. So how did I get the confirmation that the informations are correct to log me in? I thought I have to proof them with cognito

Comment: it doesn't work that way... you should read about how to log in using cognito, you will call cognito sdk (check http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/using-amazon-cognito-user-identity-pools-javascript-examples.html) and then you will just be logged in with that user... you don't need to check user.pass if you are using cognito